# googleMap is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, fadein, symfony-3.2

I'm developing an application with Symfony 3. I have a div in which I'm showing a Google map.

I'm hiding the page with

```
<div id="page_content" style="display: none">
</div>
```

then I did this:

````js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#page_content').fadeIn('slow');
})

This let me show a little animation while the browser is creating the page's doms.
But in this way the div in which there is the map is displayed only if I press the <kbd>F12</kbd> key. 

The div in which I'm displaying map: 

```html
<div class="md-card-content large-padding">
    <div id="displaymap">
        <div>
            <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
            <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 375px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
````

JavaScript function:

```js
var init_lng = '{{ bien.longitude }}';
    var init_lat = '{{ bien.latitude }}';
    var marker;
    googleMapApiLaunch(init_lng, init_lat);
    function googleMapApiLaunch(lng, lat) {
        var longitude = $('#sbc_bienbundle_bien_longitude');
        var latitude = $('#sbc_bienbundle_bien_latitude');
        {% if bien.id != 0 %}
        longitude.val(lng);
        latitude.val(lat);
        {% else %}
        if (lat === init_lat && lng === init_lng) {
            longitude.val('');
            latitude.val('');
        } else {
            longitude.val(lng);
            latitude.val(lat);
        }
        {% endif %}
        lat = parseFloat(lat);
        lng = parseFloat(lng);
        //map..
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: {
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
            },
            zoom: 14
        });
        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
        var markers = [];
        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            if (places.length === 0) {
                return;
            }
            // Clear out the old markers.
            markers.forEach(function (iMarker) {
                iMarker.setMap(null);
            });
            markers = [];
            // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            places.forEach(function (place) {
                var icon = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };
                // Create a marker for each place.
                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                }));
                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    // Only geocodes have viewport.
                    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
        //marker..
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
            },
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
        //dragend event of maker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
            //console.log(marker.getPosition());
            if (ismapped.is(':checked')) {
                longitude.val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                latitude.val(marker.getPosition().lat());
            }
        });
    }
```

What do I have to do to let the map be displayed without removing the `fadeIn('slow')` animation?

Comment: is your `md-card-content` div inside `page_content` div ?

Comment: Your `div` is `display:none` that means size is `0`, to make your code work with animation, change the animation technique from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1`, or, alternatively you can use `resize` method because when `display:block` then there is size set to div

Comment: @NadirLaskar yes

Comment: @ShekharPankaj nice idea. please can you write me a little code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you pass a callback  to the fadeIn function to do this but since you are not able to do that.

Alternatively you can do this.

> The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be
>   supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds,
>   respectively. If any other string is supplied, or if the duration
>   parameter is omitted, the default duration of  400 milliseconds is
>   used.

You can add a timeout and execute the `googleMapApiLaunch(init_lng, init_lat);` after 600ms.

```
 setTimeout(function(){
       googleMapApiLaunch(init_lng, init_lat);
    },650); // jquery slow takes 600ms
```

**Update JS**

```
    var init_lng = '{{ bien.longitude }}';
    var init_lat = '{{ bien.latitude }}';
    var marker;

    setTimeout(function(){
       googleMapApiLaunch(init_lng, init_lat);
    },650); // jquery slow takes 600ms

    function googleMapApiLaunch(lng, lat) {
        var longitude = $('#sbc_bienbundle_bien_longitude');
        var latitude = $('#sbc_bienbundle_bien_latitude');
        {% if bien.id != 0 %}
        longitude.val(lng);
        latitude.val(lat);
        {% else %}
        if (lat === init_lat && lng === init_lng) {
            longitude.val('');
            latitude.val('');
        } else {
            longitude.val(lng);
            latitude.val(lat);
        }
        {% endif %}
        lat = parseFloat(lat);
        lng = parseFloat(lng);
        //map..
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: {
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
            },
            zoom: 14
        });
        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
        var markers = [];
        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            if (places.length === 0) {
                return;
            }
            // Clear out the old markers.
            markers.forEach(function (iMarker) {
                iMarker.setMap(null);
            });
            markers = [];
            // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            places.forEach(function (place) {
                var icon = {
                    url: place.icon,
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };
                // Create a marker for each place.
                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location
                }));
                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                    // Only geocodes have viewport.
                    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
        //marker..
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng
            },
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
        //dragend event of maker
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
            //console.log(marker.getPosition());
            if (ismapped.is(':checked')) {
                longitude.val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                latitude.val(marker.getPosition().lat());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You call `googleMapApiLaunch` immediately... just do it when the fadeIn completes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#page_content').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        googleMapApiLaunch(init_lng, init_lat);
    );
});
```

**Update:** because you can't directly call googleMapApiLaunch from your main fadeIn method, what you can do is trigger an event from there.  Then have an event listener for that just to be used on the map page.  e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#page_content').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        $(this).trigger("fadeInComplete");
    );
});
```

And then in your map page JS:

```
$('#page_content').on('fadeInComplete', function () {
    googleMapApiLaunch(init_lng, init_lat);
});
```

Comment: in my actual page i'm extending from base.twig.html in wich i did $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#page_content').fadeIn('slow);
});
and i dont have map in all pages

Answer (score 1):

There are some troubles when you try to initialize a map when the div is hidden. So, what you can do is when FadeIn animation finished, trigger the map with the code below :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#page_content').fadeIn('slow', function() {
         var center = map.getCenter();
         google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
         map.setCenter(center);
    });
});
```

Be sure that `map` variable is declared when your animation is finished.

Comment: in my actual page i'm extending from base.twig.html in wich i did $(document).ready(function () { $('#page_content').fadeIn('slow); }); and i dont have map in all pages

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had a similar problem before, if you are testing it in localhost use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

It will solve your problem because some Apis like google maps don't work on localhost it need use of ngrok to work

Let's see if it work for you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#page_content').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#page_content').show();
    $('#displaymap').show(); 

});
```

Comment: that persists on server host

Comment: so it's a problem on your code I will check and update the answer